# JLabel: After overriding paintComponent(). How to make setText() render the text String?

Tags: java, swing, overriding, jlabel, paintcomponent

I wrote a subclass of JLabel, and I override `paintComponent(Graphics)` method to make a gradient background color.

This is the subclass of JLabel:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class DLabel extends JLabel
{

    Dimension size = new Dimension(70, 80);

    public DLabel()
    {
        this.setPreferredSize(size);
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(TOP, Color.white, Color.black));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        Color color1 = new Color(226, 218, 145);
        Color color2 = color1.brighter();
        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();
        GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(
                0, 0, color1, 0, h, color2);
        g2d.setPaint(gp);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    }

}
```

When I create an instance of this label it is displayed correctly, but when I use `setText(String)` the text is not rendered anything.

```
DLabel label = new DLabel();
label.setText("I am"); //No text displayed.
```

I tried different compilations of these methods after setting the text:

```
label.setOpaque(true);
label.revalidate();
label.repaint();
```

But nothing happed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What if you call the super.paintComponent(g) at the *end* of the method, so that the label draws the text *after* it draws the gradiant:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  // super.paintComponent(g);  // *** commented
  Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
  Color color1 = new Color(226, 218, 145);
  Color color2 = color1.brighter();
  int w = getWidth();
  int h = getHeight();
  GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0, 0, color1, 0, h, color2);
  g2d.setPaint(gp);
  g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
  super.paintComponent(g); // *** added
}
```

Also, as an unrelated aside, I prefer to change this:

```
Dimension size = new Dimension(70, 80);

public DLabel()
{
    this.setPreferredSize(size);
    this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(TOP, Color.white, 
         Color.black));
}
```

to this:

```
public static final Dimension PREF_SIZE = new Dimension(70, 80);

public DLabel()
{
    this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(TOP, Color.white, 
         Color.black));
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
  Dimension superDim = super.getPreferredSize();
  int width = Math.max(superDim.getWidth(), PREF_SIZE.getWidth());
  int height = Math.max(superDim.getHeight(), PREF_SIZE.getHeight()); 
  return new Dimension(width, height);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`JLabel` renders its text content within the `paintComponent` method.

You are, correctly, calling `super.paintComponent`, but are then promptly painting over it, using `fillRect`

Try moving the call to `super.paintComponent` to the end of the method (after the `fillRect` call) and leave the label as transparent

Answer (score 4):

When you did the paint it painted over the text.  Take a look at the [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net/) project.  It has a JxLabel class that will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Link is broken.