# Add decorations in JButton

Tags: java, swing, button

I am currently doing GUI development in `JavaSwing`.
I am trying to create a `button` like the `HTML` code described below using `JButton`, which was added to `getContentPane()`, but I don't know how to do it and am at a loss.

---

**Current Code:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("TITLE");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1000, 800);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JButton button = new JButton("Click Here");
    frame.getContentPane().add(button);
    button.setBackground(Color.RED);
    button.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    button.setOpaque(true);
    button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 50));

    }

  }
```

---

The entity I am trying to create is a little hard to explain by mouth, so I have tried to reproduce what I am trying to create using HTML. It is as follows:

---

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="btn">Click Here</div>

<style>
.btn {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 70px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 35px;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px #b70d0b;
  opacity: 0.7;
  cursor: pointer;
}
  .btn:hover {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .btn:active{
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
</style>
```

---

This is what it looks like when executed: The following image is my ideal in `JavaSwing`.
[image: Button]

**The question this time is:**

- Setting `opacity` to `JButton` in `JavaSwing`
- To set `border-radius` to `button`
- To set `opacity` to 1 only when the mouse `hovers` over the `button` and `MouseEvent` detects it.
- Set `box-shadow` to `5px`, and use `ActionListener` to detect the interval of active, and make it look like a `button` is being pressed.
- To reproduce the `cursor:pointer` code while the mouse is hovering over the `button`.

I am not sure if this is too much to ask or not. I am fully aware that there are too many questions, so I would appreciate it if you could answer only the ones that I can answer.

In the meantime, I have done my own Google research on the question, but none of it fits my ideal, so I am asking it here.

---

**As for what I did, here's what I did:**

I looked [here](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/java/how+do+I+change+the+opacity+of+a+JButton), but when I enter a decimal point, like `setOpacity(0.5)`, I get an error that `setOpacity(double) is undefined`.

I referred to the border-radius [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025092/border-with-rounded-corners-transparency), but nothing happened when I ran it. Perhaps there is a problem with my writing style or version. I think there is a problem with the way I wrote it or the version, but I could not find out the cause.

I tried copying the `MouseEvent` for the hover [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25393134/how-to-get-mouse-hover-event-in-java-swing), but the version may be different, or an error occurred.

So, what code should I write to achieve what I am asking?
I would appreciate it if you could help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Honestly, make an image

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hm... I think that is great idea!, but how do I add ```ActionListener``` with Image?

Comment: Well, since `JLabel` doesn't support `ActionListener`, then you'd have to use a `JButton`

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, thank you. So I think I supposed to edit the question about ```How to add decoration with JButton```

Comment: There's no "simple" way to do it.  You're going to have to create your own button class to do (or create your own look and feel delegate)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I see, thank you very much for telling me that. I will try to create my own button class as you have taught me.

Comment: I have had success in small experiments like this to use subclass of JLabel with custom paintComponent with addMouseListener/MouseAdapter, roughly like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297448/jlabel-after-overriding-paintcomponent-how-to-make-settext-render-the-text does

Comment: !! this is just what I wanted to know, thank you for sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "simple" way to do this, you're either going to have to create your own custom button (extending from `JButton`) or your own UI delegate class (which might be the preferred direction, but it's complicated)

> Why not use a `Border`

Because a `Border` can't be filled ... and if you do, it will paint over the text of the button

You should start by looking at [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html), [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [2D Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) to get a better understanding of how the solution works.

[image]

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {
        public TestPane() {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            FancyButton btn = new FancyButton();
            btn.setText("Click me");
            add(btn);
        }
    }

    public class FancyButton extends JButton {

        private int cornerRadius = 32;
        private BufferedImage backgroundImage;

        private float alpha = 0.25f;

        public FancyButton() {
            setBackground(Color.RED);
            setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            // This is important
            setBorderPainted(false);
            // This is important
            setContentAreaFilled(false);
            // This is important
            int padding = cornerRadius / 2;
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(padding, padding, padding, padding));
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    alpha = 1;
                    repaint();
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    alpha = 0.25f;
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                    backgroundImage = null;
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isOpaque() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Insets getInsets() {
            Insets insets = super.getInsets(); 
            insets.bottom += 5;
            return insets;
        }

        @Override
        public Insets getInsets(Insets insets) {
            super.getInsets(insets);
            insets.bottom += 5;
            return insets;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            if (backgroundImage == null) {
                backgroundImage = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                Graphics2D g2d = backgroundImage.createGraphics();
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                g2d.setColor(getBackground().darker());
                g2d.fillRoundRect(0, 5, getWidth(), getHeight() - 5, cornerRadius, cornerRadius);
                g2d.setColor(getBackground());
                g2d.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() - 5, cornerRadius, cornerRadius);
                g2d.dispose();
            }

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(alpha));
            g2d.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, this);
            super.paintComponent(g2d);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```